# calling a method with pre-filled parameters in php

Tags: php, methods, parameters, optional-parameters

I have created a method with pre-filled parameters (for standard behavior). But i can't call that method, when the pre-filled params are in the middle or start, but at the end of the method.

the method looks like this:

```
private function doSomething(int $id, string $type = 'standard', int $status) {
 return $type;
}
```

now when i want to call this method without writing a 2nd value, it will give me an error, that i can't call it with less characters.

```
//Somewhere in my class..
$foo = $this->doSomething($id, $status);
```

However, when i put the pre-filled parameter(s) at the end, it works normally:

```
private function doSomething(int $id, int $status, string $type = 'standard') {
```

Do i have to call this method else, when putting pre-filled params into the middle/start of it? Like this:

```
$foo = $this->doSomething($id, empty, $status);
```

Or do i just have to write pre-filled params at the end of my method?

Comment: Arguments with default values needs to be last. It doesn't really make sense to have them in any other order since you still need to pass something in it's place. However, in PHP 8, you can call the method using [named arguments](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments), which means that you can pass arguments in any order you want.

Comment: thanks for clearing this, i was curious why it is like this.

Comment: [In the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default): _"Note that any optional arguments should be specified after any required arguments, otherwise they cannot be omitted from calls."_

Comment: @Lukas Write at the end or create the parameter as an array and skip filling default params and array_merge() later inside the method.